# Boxing value objects across WinRT languages

Tags: com, windows-runtime

I am writing a C++ implementation for a WinRT interface which needs to expose a generic piece of data as an IInspectable*. This piece of data can be an IInspectable* itself, a builtin value, or one of a finite set of compound value types (e.g. Windows::Foundation::Numerics::Vector4, Matrix4x4, or a few value types defined in my library). What's the correct way to do this so that the data can be accessed from languages other than C++?

Here is how I am trying to do it. When the piece of data is a builtin value I box it in a IPropertyValue using the methods in IPropertyValueStatics, and everything works fine in all the languages I am dealing with (C++, C++/CX, C#). For structs, I have tried boxing them in an implementation of the IReference interface.

So in my IDL I have:

```
declare
{
    interface Windows.Foundation.IReference<Windows.Foundation.Numerics.Vector4>
}
```

and in a cpp:

```
using ABI::Windows::Foundation::Numerics::Vector4;
using ABI::Windows::Foundation::IReference;
struct Reference_Vector4
    : public Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClass< IReference<Vector4> >
{
    InspectableClass(L"Reference_Vector4", BaseTrust );
public:     
    STDMETHOD(get_Value)(Vector4* res) { ... }
};
```

As from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225864.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 I would expect to be able to access instances of Reference_Vector4 as IBox in C++/CX and as Nullable in C#, but this doesn't work for me. Specifically:

```
Object^ obj = <some instance of Reference_Vector4>;

IUnknown* raw = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown>(obj);
ComPtr< IReference<Vector4> > r; 
raw->QueryInterface<IReference<Vector4>>(&r); // this succeeds

auto vec = dynamic_cast<Platform::IBox<float4>^>(obj); // this fails
auto vec2 = reinterpret_cast<Platform::IBox<float4>^>(obj); // this works (can read the correct float4)
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: That should be `IBox<T>^` with a hat, since it is an interface type, not a value type. Examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699861.aspx). Also, it looks like your `T` changed from `Vector4` to `float4`, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: You're right about the '^', they got lost while copying the test code. It doesn't solve the issue though.
Windows::Numerics::float4 is the C++/CX projection of ABI::Windows::Numerics::Vector4. Instances of Vector4 appearing in an IDL will be mapped to float4 when used in C++/CX (and also, IBox<Vector4> doesn't even compile), so I would expect IReference<Vector4> to be mapped to IBox<float4>.

Comment: Hi Filippo,
Did you mange to solve the problem?
If you could post what you ended up doing that would help other people too (including me).
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, no luck until now.